# c++ check if integer variable

Tags: c++, validation, loops, integer

User enters date, currently validated to ensure the value is between 1 & 31 inclusive.

However, if they type a non integer value in, it just constantly repeats the error message in an infinite loop.

I have looked around for the answer but everyone else who has asked appears to be far more advanced at c++ than I am, and therefore I don't even understand their initial code.

Here's the code

```
void Menu::setDate()
{
    date = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter todays date: (as an integer) ";
    do
    {
        std::cin >> date;   
        if (date > 0 && date < 32)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Error: Please enter todays date: (as an integer) ";
    }
    while (true);
 }
```

Comment: @juanchopanza But it should get the input, check it, then break if its valid, or re-get the input. But it loops. I think its something like, it gets the input even though you don't press enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is when an invalid integer is entered, the stream gets error and sets to failbit. Therefore, you need to clear it before you can use I/O operations again. Try this:

```
void Menu::setDate()
{
    date = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter todays date: (as an integer) ";

    while(true){
        std::cin >> date;
        if(date > 0 && date < 32){
            break;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Error, please enter today's date (as an integer):" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: this has stopped it looping and constantly outputting the error message nonstop, however it now outputs the error message anytime that anything is entered, even an integer

Comment: @user3001499 Fixed, can you try now?

Comment: @user3001499 Just one more note to be aware of, this would work perfectly, but in case the user inputs a value like "anyintegerandletter" (example: 12f) it would take 12 as integer and ignore the f, therefore it would be a valid input.

Comment: okay thanks for the tip, any chance you could quickly outline what cin.clear() and cin.ignore(...) do. So that I learn as oppose to just copying?

Comment: `cin.clear();` clears the errors (failbit) on the stream so that future I/O operations will work correctly and `cin.ignore();` ignores all the characters in the stream until new line is found, basically ignoring everything else on the same line to prevent an error again.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when a non-digit is entered the stream gets erroneous state. You should clear it and skip invalid input. For example

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with checking `cin.fail()`.
This is how you get the infinite loop: when `std::cin >> date` fails, `date` is likely to be unchanged. So you have effectively this:

```
do
{
    if (date > 0 && date < 32)
    {
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Error: Please enter todays date: (as an integer) ";
}
while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when `std::cin>>a` encounters a decimal point it stops taking further input. And the remaining number stays in the input buffer.

```
int a,b,c;

std::cin>>a;
std::cin>>b;
std::cin>>c;
```

If the user enters *1.9*, in the first step *a* becomes *1* and *.9* remains in the input buffer. The next `std::cin` statements skip inputting as the first character in the input buffer is a decimal point. The buffer is cleared when a float input is taken.